# Spark submit throws ClassNotFoundException for the class file which is in same jar file

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a jar file through Airflow and spark submit operator but getting ClassNotFoundException for the class which is in same jar file.

DAG python code:

```
    operator = EzSparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id='java_task1',
        conn_id='spark_opsi',
        java_class='com.test.process.MAO04HBaseDriver',
    application='/mapr/datalake/test/my-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar',
        executor_cores='3',
        executor_memory='10g',
        num_executors='5',
        driver_memory='3g',
        application_args=["/datalake/test/database/cornerstone/hbase/medm4h","/datalake/test/database/cornerstone/hbase/medm4d","/datalake/test/database/cornerstone/hbase/medm4f","/datalake/test/database/edps/hbase/medmdc","/datalake/test/properties/standard_properties.cfg"],
        conf={
            "set mapreduce.job.queuename":queuename,
            "numReduce":40,
            "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition": "True",
            "spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode": "nonstrict",
            "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead": "4096M",
            "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy": "LEGACY",
            "spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy":"LEGACY",
            "spark.sql.legacy.charVarcharAsString":"True",
            "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat":"True",
            "spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.read.ahead.enabled":"false",
            "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold":"104857600",
            "spark.port.maxRetries":"100",
            "queue":queuename
            },
        dag=dag
    )
start>>start_email>>operator>>end_email>>failed_email
```

Java Code: MAO04HBaseDriver is main class. MAO04Writable class is being used in main class.

```
package com.test.process;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import com.mapr.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import com.test.process.MAO04HBaseReducer.ErrorOccurred;
import com.test.writable.MAO04Writable;

public class MAO04HBaseDriver {

    private static String hbase_MAO_DTL = null;
    private static String hbase_MAO_HDR = null;
    private static String hbase_MAO_FTR = null;
    private static String hbase_Data_Check = null;
    private static String confFile = null;
    private static String queueName = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        
        try {
            Configuration hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

            if(otherArgs.length != 5){
                System.out.println("Total 5 arguments are required for this process, invalid arguments supplied!!");
                System.exit(-3);
            }

            hbase_MAO_HDR = otherArgs[0];
            hbase_MAO_DTL = otherArgs[1];
            hbase_MAO_FTR = otherArgs[2];
            hbase_Data_Check = otherArgs[3];
            confFile = otherArgs[4];

            loadConfigurationFile(confFile, hconf);
            hconf.set("hbase_MAO_HDR", hbase_MAO_HDR);
            hconf.set("hbase_MAO_FTR", hbase_MAO_FTR);
            hconf.set("hbase_MAO_DTL", hbase_MAO_DTL);

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Job job = new Job(hconf, "OPSIDataCheck");
            job.setJarByClass(MAO04HBaseDriver.class);
            job.setReducerClass(MAO04HBaseReducer.class);
            
            if (hconf.get("numReduce")!=null) {
                job.setNumReduceTasks(Integer.parseInt(hconf.get("numReduce")));    
            } else {
                job.setNumReduceTasks(32);
            }
            
            List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<Scan>();
            
            Scan scan1 = new Scan();
            scan1.setCaching(500);
            scan1.setCacheBlocks(false);
            scan1.setAttribute("scan.attributes.table.name", Bytes.toBytes(hbase_MAO_HDR));
            System.out.println(scan1.getAttribute("scan.attributes.table.name"));
            scans.add(scan1);
            
            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
                    scans,               // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
                    MAO04Mapper.class,     // mapper class
                    Text.class,         // mapper output key
                    MAO04Writable.class,  // mapper output value
                    job);

            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(hbase_Data_Check, MAO04HBaseReducer.class, job);

            System.out.println("Before OPSIDataCheck job wait for completion");
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
            
            if((job.getCounters().findCounter(ErrorOccurred.ErrorPresent).getValue())>0){
                System.exit(-9);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
    
    private static void loadConfigurationFile(String confFile, Configuration hconf) throws IOException {
        try {
            Path path = new Path(confFile);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hconf);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));

            String record = null;
            while ((record=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(record.contains("QUEUE")){
                    System.out.println("record :"+record);
                    String [] words = record.split("=");
                    if (words.length>0){
                        queueName = words[1];
                    } else {
                        queueName = "opsiuxg_q1";   
                    }
                } 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading the configuration file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Java code of MAO04Writable class.

```
package com.test.writable;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class MAO04Writable implements WritableComparable<MAO04Writable>{

    private Text rec_typ, file_key, mdcr_adv_cntrct_id, hdr_rep_id, hdr_rep_dt, hdr_sbmsn_file_typ, hdr_file_name,
                 dtl_sub_cli_sk, dtl_encntr_icn,
                 ftr_rep_id, ftr_tot_num_rec;
    
    //Default constructor
    public MAO04Writable() {
        this.rec_typ = new Text();
        this.file_key = new Text();
        this.mdcr_adv_cntrct_id = new Text();
        this.hdr_rep_id = new Text();
        this.hdr_rep_dt = new Text();
        this.hdr_sbmsn_file_typ = new Text();
        this.hdr_file_name = new Text();
        this.dtl_sub_cli_sk = new Text();
        this.dtl_encntr_icn = new Text();
        this.ftr_rep_id = new Text();
        this.ftr_tot_num_rec = new Text();
    }

    public MAO04Writable(Text rec_typ, Text file_key, Text mdcr_adv_cntrct_id, Text hdr_rep_id, Text hdr_rep_dt, Text hdr_sbmsn_file_typ, Text hdr_file_name, 
                         Text dtl_sub_cli_sk, Text dtl_encntr_icn, 
                         Text ftr_rep_id, Text ftr_tot_num_rec) {
        this.rec_typ = rec_typ;
        this.file_key = file_key;
        this.mdcr_adv_cntrct_id = mdcr_adv_cntrct_id;
        this.hdr_rep_id = hdr_rep_id;
        this.hdr_rep_dt = hdr_rep_dt;
        this.hdr_sbmsn_file_typ = hdr_sbmsn_file_typ;
        this.hdr_file_name = hdr_file_name;
        this.dtl_sub_cli_sk = dtl_sub_cli_sk;
        this.dtl_encntr_icn = dtl_encntr_icn;
        this.ftr_rep_id = ftr_rep_id;
        this.ftr_tot_num_rec = ftr_tot_num_rec;
    }

    public Text getRec_typ() {
        return rec_typ;
    }

    public void setRec_typ(Text rec_typ) {
        this.rec_typ = rec_typ;
    }

    public Text getFile_key() {
        return file_key;
    }

    public void setFile_key(Text file_key) {
        this.file_key = file_key;
    }

    public Text getMdcr_adv_cntrct_id() {
        return mdcr_adv_cntrct_id;
    }

    public void setMdcr_adv_cntrct_id(Text mdcr_adv_cntrct_id) {
        this.mdcr_adv_cntrct_id = mdcr_adv_cntrct_id;
    }

    public Text getHdr_rep_id() {
        return hdr_rep_id;
    }

    public void setHdr_rep_id(Text hdr_rep_id) {
        this.hdr_rep_id = hdr_rep_id;
    }

    public Text getHdr_rep_dt() {
        return hdr_rep_dt;
    }

    public void setHdr_rep_dt(Text hdr_rep_dt) {
        this.hdr_rep_dt = hdr_rep_dt;
    }

    public Text getHdr_sbmsn_file_typ() {
        return hdr_sbmsn_file_typ;
    }

    public void setHdr_sbmsn_file_typ(Text hdr_sbmsn_file_typ) {
        this.hdr_sbmsn_file_typ = hdr_sbmsn_file_typ;
    }

    public Text getHdr_file_name() {
        return hdr_file_name;
    }

    public void setHdr_file_name(Text hdr_file_name) {
        this.hdr_file_name = hdr_file_name;
    }

    public Text getDtl_sub_cli_sk() {
        return dtl_sub_cli_sk;
    }

    public void setDtl_sub_cli_sk(Text dtl_sub_cli_sk) {
        this.dtl_sub_cli_sk = dtl_sub_cli_sk;
    }

    public Text getDtl_encntr_icn() {
        return dtl_encntr_icn;
    }

    public void setDtl_encntr_icn(Text dtl_encntr_icn) {
        this.dtl_encntr_icn = dtl_encntr_icn;
    }

    public Text getFtr_rep_id() {
        return ftr_rep_id;
    }

    public void setFtr_rep_id(Text ftr_rep_id) {
        this.ftr_rep_id = ftr_rep_id;
    }

    public Text getFtr_tot_num_rec() {
        return ftr_tot_num_rec;
    }

    public void setFtr_tot_num_rec(Text ftr_tot_num_rec) {
        this.ftr_tot_num_rec = ftr_tot_num_rec;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        rec_typ.readFields(arg0); //static value "HDR" will be populated
        file_key.readFields(arg0);
        mdcr_adv_cntrct_id.readFields(arg0);
        hdr_rep_id.readFields(arg0);
        hdr_rep_dt.readFields(arg0);
        hdr_sbmsn_file_typ.readFields(arg0);
        hdr_file_name.readFields(arg0);
        dtl_sub_cli_sk.readFields(arg0);
        dtl_encntr_icn.readFields(arg0);
        ftr_rep_id.readFields(arg0);
        ftr_tot_num_rec.readFields(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        rec_typ.write(arg0); //static value "HDR" will be populated
        file_key.write(arg0);
        mdcr_adv_cntrct_id.write(arg0);
        hdr_rep_id.write(arg0);
        hdr_rep_dt.write(arg0);
        hdr_sbmsn_file_typ.write(arg0);
        hdr_file_name.write(arg0);
        dtl_sub_cli_sk.write(arg0);
        dtl_encntr_icn.write(arg0);
        ftr_rep_id.write(arg0);
        ftr_tot_num_rec.write(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MAO04Writable o) {
        return file_key.compareTo(o.file_key);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((file_key == null) ? 0 : file_key.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MAO04Writable other = (MAO04Writable) obj;
        if (file_key == null) {
            if (other.file_key != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!file_key.equals(other.file_key))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MAO04Writable [rec_typ=" + rec_typ + ", file_key=" + file_key + ", mdcr_adv_cntrct_id="
                + mdcr_adv_cntrct_id + ", hdr_rep_id=" + hdr_rep_id + ", hdr_rep_dt=" + hdr_rep_dt
                + ", hdr_sbmsn_file_typ=" + hdr_sbmsn_file_typ + ", hdr_file_name=" + hdr_file_name
                + ", dtl_sub_cli_sk=" + dtl_sub_cli_sk + ", dtl_encntr_icn=" + dtl_encntr_icn + ", ftr_rep_id="
                + ftr_rep_id + ", ftr_tot_num_rec=" + ftr_tot_num_rec + "]";
        
    }
}
```

Exception message:

```
    24/01/17 02:41:44 ERROR SparkSubmit$$anon$2: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.test.writable.MAO04Writable not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.test.writable.MAO04Writable not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2394)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapOutputValueClass(JobConf.java:833)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapOutputValueClass(JobContextImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(TableMapReduceUtil.java:926)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:507)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:463)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TableMapReduceUtil.java:440)
at com.test.process.MAO04HBaseDriver.main(MAO04HBaseDriver.java:120)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:974)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:179)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1076)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1085)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.test.writable.MAO04Writable not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2362)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2386)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.test.writable.MAO04Writable not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2268)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2360)
... 20 more
ERROR - Task failed with exception
```